# flutter and firestore: pod install problem

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I added cloud_firestore in my code I got the following error:

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update
```

After doing pod repo update it did not help. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Podspec.lock` on you ios folder

`cd ios`
`pod install`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to build the project from Xcode, in that case you need to run pod install:

```
cd iOS

pod deintegrate 

pod install
```

Or what works for me most of the time is to firstly build it with vscode and only after that build it with Xcode, that works because when building flutter app with vs code, very time you build it vscode is running above mentioned commands automatically.